# Trying to get jquery to call a submit, having issues in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link_to form helper, that has an id:

```
<%=  link_to "NEXT", next_wizard_path, :method => :put, :id => 'my-link-check' %>
```

I want this link to to submit the form that is on the page (its actually a partial but that shouldn't matter its all one page when rendered).  So I put in some jquery on the top of the header partial:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-link-check').click(function(event){
    var form = document.getElementById("edit_put");
    if(form!=null)
        form.submit();
    //event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href, dont think we want this
    });
}); 
</script>
```

In an odd twist the form.submit does indeed work, IF i am in firebug with a breakpoints set and specifically step through the code, if i do not, it runs the code but the submit does not actually work.  I am so confused as to what is going on, or why it would be behaving like this.  I suspect its in how I am using the jquery call as I am not well versed in jquery at all.

I should note, this is to save data on a form that is being served and helped with [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked), which is this wizard gem for ruby on rails.

I should also note the author of wicked suggested to save data between "wizard pages" to submit data asynchronously whenever the form is touched via ajax:

```
def update

# save logic here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
    # whatever
  end
  format.html do
     render_wizard
  end
end
```

though I have no clue, is that making form_for in our view remote => true ?  I suspect it is more involved than that.

I also tried having the link_to method be a put method, this did call the Update action in the controller, but it passed no information so it was not saving any form changes...its why I thought the submit action call thru javascript was a good solution, apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not use it here: `var form = document.getElementById("edit_put");`.  You can write: `var form = $("#edit_put");`

Answer (score 1):

Why have you commented out `event.preventDefault();` line? Does the link with `my-link-check` id lead to actual address?

Looks like the browser just changed (or reload) the page, and script execution is terminated. With break point everything goes OK.

Try to uncomment `event.preventDefault();` or put `return false;` after `form.submit();`

Comment: this was an attempt to make wicked behave the way it should, let me try the above and see if it works.

Comment: okay indeed the return false worked (event.preventDefault() had no effect)....so that saves the form.  But the link_to wont follow now to the next page (this is correct as it returns false) so , no way to make it still goto the next page?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that jQuery `submit` only works on a jQuery object, so it should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-link-check').click(function(event){
    var form = $("#edit_put");
    if(form!=null)
        $(form).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: ok tried that, still no dice.  It is so strange, runs fine, doesn't throw an error that I can see...and DOES submit when a break point is put on the var form and I step through all the way thru the .submit which calls a .apply somewhere deep in jquery.

Comment: Any chance `#my-link-check` has `name="submit"`? If so, give it a different name.

Comment: well for some reason if i try to give the form_for an id, its always renamed with edit_put that i have seen.  I am not sure crowjonah what you mean by the #my-link-check has name="submit" ?

Comment: In the rendered HTML markup, does the form submit input have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Inside the name there is `<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save Document" />`, this what you mean?